# XAMARIN - Android watchface taking long time to install to the watch

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, wear-os, watchface

I made a simple watch face using visual studio 2015.
The solution has 2 projects (mobile and wear).
I'm deploying as "release" signing everything fine, it installs in the phone and in the watch, but the problem is that it's taking 30 minutes to hours to sync and install in the watch.

I have already tried force sync apps from android wear app, unpaired and paired again, everything.

The same code, in android studio install just fine. Is there some bug or adjust that are related to the way/time it installs?

I'm using VS 2015 community, installing in a huawei watch.

thanks

Comment: You may want to first visit this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/connecting-to-web-services-with-android-wear/) to know how you can have a stable connection which is necessary when syncing. In addition to that, this [article](https://www.slideshare.net/gertcominotto/developing-for-wearables-with-xamarin) might also help. It gives guidelines and also the components that you must consider when developing an Android watch face using Xamarin .

Comment: The reason why this is taking so long is quiet simply the fact that Xamarin apps needs a runtime. The runtime has a considerable footprint, and transferring it takes time.